# puppet 3.8.x variable can't apply to template

Tags: puppet, erb

module/bareos_backup_client/manifests/init.pp:

```
class bareos_backup_client {
      @@file { "${fqdn}-bareos-client.conf":
            mode => 600,
            owner => bareos,
            group => bareos,
            path => "/etc/bareos/director.d/${fqdn}-client.conf",
            content => template("bareos_backup_client/bareos-dir-cliententry.erb"),
            tag => 'bareos-client',
            notify => Service[bareos-dir],

    }        
}
```

module/bareos_backup_client/templates/bareos-dir-cliententry.erb:

```
  <% if @clientrunbeforejob -%>
  ClientRunBeforeJob  = "<%=  @clientrunbeforejob %>"
  <% end -%>
  <% if @clientrunafterjob -%>
  ClientRunAfterJob = "<%=  @clientrunafterjob %>"
  <% end -%>
```

manifests/nodes/server_1.pp:

```
  include bareos_backup_client
  $clientrunbeforejob = "apple"
```

Why clientrunbeforejob variable can't inject into erb template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try and use [dynamic scoping](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/scope_and_puppet.html#an-example-of-dynamic-lookup). This has not worked in years, and for good reason!

You will likely want to pass this value as a [class parameter](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_classes.html#class-parameters-and-variables).

```
class bareos_backup_client($clientrunbeforejob) {
  ...
}
```

Then declare it like

```
class { 'bareos_backup_client':
  clientrunbeforejob => 'apple'
}
```